# MySQL - SELECT query with variable in it won't execute

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dynamic, execute

So I'm trying to create a dynamic SELECT query that will only show the columns that were chosen previously and stored in a string `$stANCol`.

```
$idServ = 17; //$_GET(Selected);
$queryIsSelected = "SELECT $stANCol FROM camposservico WHERE idServico = ? ;";              
$stmt = $mydb->prepare($queryIsSelected);        
$stmt->bind_param("i", $idServ);                
$stmt->execute();
```

The echo from `$stANCol` is

```
morada, dieta, dataIntervencao, sondaVesical, ecd,
sinaisVitais, riscoQueda, riscoAlergia, riscoTransfusao, riscoMultiRisco, obsQuadro, obs
```

and these are the columns that may change depending on what is selected or not.

The echo from `$queryIsSelected` is

```
SELECT morada, dieta, dataIntervencao, sondaVesical, ecd, 
sinaisVitais, riscoQueda, riscoAlergia, riscoTransfusao,
riscoMultiRisco, obsQuadro, obs FROM camposservico WHERE idServico = ? ;
```

And this query works just fine on phpMyAdmin, hence my question. Am I doing something wrong or is it impossible to have a string variable used on the SELECT?

**EDIT:** Turns out there was nothing wrong with any of this code, had a pending statement lurking on my page that was messing with this one. Thanks for all the replies everyone :)

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM camposservico WHERE idServico = ?` work?

Comment: Oh, actually now it doesn't anymore. I messed up somewhere else then. I guess the question is irrelevant now. Thanks for the reply, sorry for wasting time.

Answer (score 3):

remove the ; from your query

your's:

```
$queryIsSelected = "SELECT $stANCol FROM camposservico WHERE idServico = ? ;";
```

after removing ;

```
$queryIsSelected = "SELECT $stANCol FROM camposservico WHERE idServico = ? ";
```

it will get execute.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that didn't make a difference. And I had it without ";" before, I actually added it when I wrote the question here :)

Comment: what does ? stands for in idServico = ?

Comment: The idServico in the WHERE clause is being set on the bind_param, hence the "?". It will always be an int that is also chosen by the users.

Comment: what error are you getting? try, manually insert the value instead of ?.. and see whether its getting execute or not? e.g.    $queryIsSelected = "SELECT $stANCol FROM camposservico WHERE idServico = 111 ";

Comment: That's exactly what I tried first. I keep getting the "Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object ...".

Comment: there can be other error as well. try executing select 1 from dual. So that you will come to know that there is something wrong with other things like connection or something else

Comment: Just tried that, selecting only 1 column and I get the execute() error again. Which is really weird because I'm doing a query just fine before this code block, like 5 lines above it actually. And I closed that statement, so there isn't anything pending.

Comment: Ended up answering myself. Turns out there was a pending statement lurking around. Thanks for all the replies :)

Answer (score 0):

I have added single quotes in your query

```
$queryIsSelected = "SELECT $stANCol FROM `camposservico` WHERE `idServico` = ? ";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it's stil the same. Most of my queries don't have any single quotes, and still execute. The problem must be something else that is really getting on my nerves

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$queryIsSelected = "SELECT $stANCol FROM camposservico WHERE idServico = ? ;";              
$stmt = $mydb->prepare($queryIsSelected);        
$stmt->bind_param("i", $idServ);  

// move this to here
$idServ = 17;

$stmt->execute();
```

---

also try to use something like this for debugging

```
if($stmt === false) {
   trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $queryIsSelected . ' Error: ' . $mydb->errno . ' ' . $mydb->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: Updated answer, maybe something is going wrong with your statement.